# Why i cant acces body and th in my css when i use bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Heres the code of my CSS.

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

th
{
    text-align: center;
}

#base_form_input
{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 7.5%;
    position: absolute;
}

#formLogin
{
    width: 87%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The div id works, but body and th not affected. I using bootsrap, and then i cant settings my body or table or th. There is some way without adding id or class to it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css"> 
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

        <script type = 'text/javascript' src = "<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type = 'text/javascript' src = "<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('.table').click(function(e)
                {
                    alert($(e.target).text());    
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: add the script after body

Comment: i just want change the color, but it cannot change, how i can change the body background-color ?

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your custom stylesheet after the Bootstrap stylesheet, if there are two CSS declarations the last one is the one that gets precedence.

AKA just move the link to the Bootstrap stylesheet before the link to your custom one.

On a side note, you can place `!important` after a styling and it will force it to rule over everything else.